# League Table order points

Tags: java

I need to have the teams sortable by order of points, from most to least, i have that i have to write a new method and can make changes to the class header.
I was thinking of using this as my method, but it would put the teams in order of least to most :S so i dont know what way to fix it, also i dont know what changes i would need to make to the class header if any!

> public void orderPoints()

```
{
 List<String> points = new ArrayList<String>();
 Collections.sort(points);
}
```

I know i can use Collections.max and min but unsure how i would filter the rest of the points in

Code for rest of the class

> public class League 
>   {    /* instance
>   variables */
>     private Team name;
>   private int points;
>
> /**
>       * Constructor for objects of class League.
>       */    public League(Team aname)
>   {
>         super();
>
> ```
>   name = aName;
>
>   points = 0;    }
> ```
>
> /**
>       * Returns the receiver's name Team
>       */    public Team getName()    {
>         return this.name;    }
>
> ```
>       /**
> * Returns the receiver's points
> */    public int getPoints()    {
>   return points;    }
>      /**
> * Sets the receiver's points
> */    public void setPoints(int aPoints)    {
>   this.points = aPoints;    }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you want to reverse the sorting of your List you can use `Collections.sort(points, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: Thats the way i was going gedim but it kept asking me to declare the variable collections which ive never needed to do before, this confused me

Comment: public void points()
      
   {
       List<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       Collections.sort(points, Collections.reverseOrder());    
    }